# Cannot convert double into double[][] error in java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Okay so I'm still working on a matrix project for my APCS class, and I am currently trying to figure out how to get the user to input all the numbers for the matrix. Right now I have a setNums class that uses the Rows and Columns already inputted to throw up a bunch of inputboxes and then inputs those numbers into a 2 dimensional array like so:

```
public void setNums(String Matrixnum){
    for (int i = 1; i <= myRows; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= myColumns; j++){
            String StrNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, Matrixnum + " Row " + i + " Column " + j + " enter number:");
            myNums[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(StrNum);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a getNums class that should go through the array and return them one by one, when I need the numbers later on for adding, subtracting, and multiplying the matrices:

```
public double[][] getNums(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= myRows; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= myColumns; j++) {
            return myNums[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I try to return myNums, it says "cannot convert from double to double[][]" I don't understand why the code thinks it's a double and not a double[][]. I initialized it correctly:

```
private double[][] myNums;
```

...and I made sure my parsedouble was outputting to the array, which was the issue in a similar thread I found. This is my first time working with 2 dimensional arrays, so I bet there's something simple here that I don't understand. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to return a `double` as you are returning an element of your `double[][]`

Comment: `public double[][] getNums(){` If you are returning a single number, the return type should not be an array: `public double getNums(){`

Comment: Instead of trying to return a single element of your array you need to return the entire array. So remove the 2 for loops and return the `return myNums;`

Comment: You seem to misunderstand that way that arrays work.  `myNums[i][j]` is the `double` stored at index i and j, not the entire array, which would just be `myNums`.

Comment: In other news, the method `getNums()` doesn't work the way you want.  It won't return numbers "one at a time."  It returns the first number at position `myNums[1][1]` and then quits.

Comment: You code has a number of problems other than the mixup of double[][] and double. Most importantly, an array in java runs from 0 to size-1. Therefore, the loops should be something like this: `for (int i = 0; i < myRows; i++)`. Also, returning in the middle of a loop (likely at the first iteration) does not make sense at all (without checking any specific conditions). You need to return _after_ the loops are done (and after doing whatever you wanted to do in the loops).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler returns this error `Cannot convert double into double[][]`

because your are actually returning single double number instead of your double array `double[][]` that you defined as return type of your method `getNums()`

Instead you can fix the problem by returning only `myNums` array:

```
public double[][] getNums(){
        return myNums;
}
```

Also you can declare another method if you want to get any specific number from your array by using array indexes `i` and `j`:

```
public double getNumber(int i, int j){
        return myNums[i][j];
}
```